# Qt and Matlab Mixed Programming

Tags: c++, matlab, qt

I have a problem when I use Qt with MATLAB mixed programming. I tested an example but it failed. Here is my code.
First is my pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = paintertest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    test1.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    test1.h \
    mat.h \
    matrix.h \
    mclbase.h \
    mclcppclass.h \
    mclmcr.h \
    mclmcrrt.h \
    tmwtypes.h \
    MyAdde.h \
    engine.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += D:/program/engineering/armadillo-8.200.2/include
INCLUDEPATH += D:/program/engineering/sigpack


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lblas_win32_MT
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lblas_win32_MTd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lblas_win32_MT

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -llapack_win32_MT
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -llapack_win32_MTd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -llapack_win32_MT

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lliblapacke

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32

INCLUDEPATH += D:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/include
INCLUDEPATH += D:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/include/win32
LIBS +=-LD:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -llibmx
LIBS +=-LD:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -llibmat
LIBS +=-LD:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -llibmex
LIBS +=-LD:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -lmclmcr
LIBS +=-LD:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -lmclmcrrt
LIBS +=-LD:/program/engineering/matlabR2014a/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -llibeng

#INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Qt/paintertest
#LIBS += -LC:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Qt/paintertest -lMyAdde



win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lMyAdde
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lMyAdde
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lMyAdde

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
```

And next is my mainwindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
#include "test1.h"
#include <QVariant>
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
#include "sigpack.h"
#include "MyAdde.h"
#include "mat.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mclbase.h"
#include "mclcppclass.h"
#include "mclmcr.h"
#include "mclmcrrt.h"
#include "tmwtypes.h"
#include "engine.h"
```

And next is my mainwindow.cpp:

```
 double a=6;
    double b = 9;
    double c;
    if(MyAddeInitialize()){
        qDebug()<<"ok";
    }
    mwArray mwA(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
    mwArray mwB(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
    mwArray mwC(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
    mwA.SetData(&a, 1);
    mwB.SetData(&b, 1);
    MyAdde(1, mwC, mwA, mwB);
    c = mwC.Get(1, 1);
    cout<<"c"<<c;
    MyAddeTerminate();
    mclTerminateApplication();
```

The MyAdde.h/MyAdde.dll/MyAdde.lib is my Matlab code. Here is my Matlab code:

```
 function [ c ] = MyAdde( a, b )
 c = a+b;
 end
```

I use MATLAB to generate MyAdde.h/MyAdde.dll/MyAdde.lib and I add this file to my Qt pro file.But some error happened.This is my Qt error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Qt\paintertest\mainwindow.cpp:23: error: undefined reference to `MyAdde(int, mwArray&, mwArray const&, mwArray const&)'
```

I checked the MyAdde.h and I found this code:

```
 extern LIB_MyAdde_CPP_API void MW_CALL_CONV MyAdde(int nargout, mwArray& c, const mwArray& a, const mwArray& b);
```

I thinked of that the question is caused by const mwArray& and mwArray const&. I can't understand the reason. I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a linker error , so it has compiled fine but the link failed

It's probably this stuff that is wrong

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lMyAdde
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lMyAdde
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lMyAdde
```

What are you trying to achieve ? first and second lines should normally not be the same if you have a debug and release version of you MyAdde dll

Comment: I just want to use Qt with MatLab to do Signal Process. Because I can't find some library to do Signal Process so I think I can do some processing work in MatLab and generate dll and lib file use Matlab. And I edit ui use Qt. The question is my first simple example:c = a+b. How I change the code?

Comment: The code you have been mentioned is generated by the Qt Creator. So although I have some doubt with this code but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: I only have one dll file generate by the matlab.